# How can I generate pseudorandom numbers in p3sim assembler

Tags: assembly

How can I do it if I want to generate numbers between x and y.Or how could  I import the time in miliseconds if I wanted to use that method

Comment: seeding a PRNG with the time is a separate question from choosing a PRNG algorithm to generate a (uniform?) distribution of integers over a range.  What quality of random numbers do you need?  Like cryptographically secure?  Good enough for numeric simulations?  Or super-simple like a linear congurential generator?  I don't know p3, but if it doesn't have divide / modulo then an xorshift+ generator might be the easiest fast PRNG to implement.

Comment: Just super simple hex numbers in a range

Comment: Hex is a text serialization format for numbers.  It has nothing to do with how you generate the binary integer in a register or memory.  Anyway, if you want simple, google linear congruential generator and/or xorshift+ and take your pick.

Comment: hex as in hexadecimal.Thanks

Comment: That's what I was talking about.  Numbers in registers are in binary.  You can convert a number to / from a hex or decimal ASCII string to print it or read it, but `add` instructions work on binary numbers.